# Is there a way to track how many instances a specific word is said in Speech Recognition?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I've been reading through the Android docs and Google searches on Speech Recognition looking for something that tracks how many times or instances a specific word has been said. I understand that it returns an array list of possible matches with how confident of a match it believes it to be. What I want to know is there a way to pull how many times it believes "cat" (for example) is said during its "recording"? IE it believes "cat" is said 3 times, so it returns 3 instances of "cat" and for each instance reacts to it. Kinda like saying Beetlejuice 3 times and he appears. Is there a direct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are returning the data as a ArrayList

```
ArrayList<String> s = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        String[] split = s.get(0).split(" ");
        int count = 0;
        for (String t : split) {
            if (t.contains(split[0])) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        //count now equals number of repeats of a word within a phrase
```

Comment: Cool, just have to specify the word its looking for prior to getting the count then, correct?

Comment: Nope because it will take the first word and will then count the number of incidences of that first word. To use a specific word replace "split[0]" with your word of choice. You can also get it to count many words simultaneously buy putting more if/else blocks with many different words and more counters.

Comment: Was looking for that, and that would explain my System.out prints for count lol. However, after replacing "split[0]" with a specific word its no longer providing a system.out for count. I've tried both passing in a string as "cat" or as cat from String cat= ("cat"). Which is the appropriate way?

Comment: Try the above code where I've changed contentEquals to contains. This means if string t contains the letters (for example) "cat" in any part of the word it will return true. How's that for you?